# send SMS from mobile browser 

Tags: html, mobile, blackberry, sms

Can I send SMS after clicking on link in mobile browser? Similarily to [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2166-how-to-send-a-text-message-from-your-mobile-website/) link - 
but it's not compatible with BlackBerry, Openwave (Myriad) browser. Is there all browser compatible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short article from BB Developer Zone:

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.message.sms.html